# Non-elementary form of $\int\limits_{x=0}^\infty{{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{K_1}({2\sqrt{\frac{{ab}}{x}}}){x^{M-1}}{e^{-\frac{x}{c}}}dx}$?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Is this the correct way to rewrite this integral as non-elementary function give that $a,b,c$ are real positive number and $M$ is a positive integer

$I =\int\limits_{x = 0}^\infty  {{x^{ - \frac{1}{2}}}{K_1}\left( {2\sqrt {\frac{{ab}}{x}} } \right){x^{M - 1}}{e^{ - \frac{x}{c}}}dx}$ ?

${K_1}\left( {. } \right)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind

I have already try this with Mathematica and see that for the case $ab = 0.5$ and $c>0$, this integral would result in a Meijer G–functions as follow
[image]

Since ${\left( {{e^{ - \ln \left( {0.5} \right)}}} \right)^M} = {e^{ - 0.693147M}}$ my guess would be that $I$ could be rewrite as

$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt {\frac{1}{{ab}}} {\left( {\frac{1}{{ab}}} \right)^M}MeijerG\left[ {\left\{ {\left\{ {} \right\},\left\{ {} \right\}} \right\},\left\{ {\left\{ {0,1 - M, - M} \right\},\left\{ {} \right\}} \right\},\frac{{ab}}{c}} \right]$

But I do not know how to derive such result, please help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Writing the integral as
$$I(k) =\int\limits_{x = 0}^\infty  {{x^{ - \frac{1}{2}}}{K_1}\left( {2\sqrt {\frac{{k}}{x}} } \right){x^{M - 1}}{e^{ - \frac{x}{c}}}dx}$$
Making $x=4 k t$, the result is as you did expect
$$I(k)=\frac{1}{2} k^{M-\frac{1}{2}} G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(\frac{k}{c}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,1-M,-M
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I was about writing some solutions for you new question but I prefered to give up (too long to type).

Comment: sorry for not voting you answer but this answer I cannot explain it to my colleague